# How to decorate text element label and input separately?

Tags: zend-framework, zend-form, decorator

I have a text element declared this way:

```
$name = $this->createElement('text', 'name');
$name->setLabel('imie:');
```

I want to decorate this element to get it rendered like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <span class="label">
    <label for="name" class="highlight">Name</label>
  </span>
  <span class="formw">
    <input type="text"  id="someid" name="name" class="textfield">
  </span>
</div>
```

I can't manage to get it work properly.
Could somebody help me with setting decorators for that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the viewScript Decorator:

the partial @ `views/scripts/_partial.phtml (name it what you want)

```
<form action="<?php echo $this->element->getAction() ?>"
      method="<?php echo $this->element->getMethod() ?>">
    <div class="row">
        <span class="label">
            <?php echo $this->element->name->renderLabel() //render the label for element ?>
        </span>
        <span class="formw">
            <?php echo $this->element->name->renderViewHelper() //render just the input of the element ?>
        </span>
        <?php echo $this->element->submit //render the whole submit element ?>
    </div>
</form>
```

In your form set the decorator :

```
class Application_Form_NewForm extends Zend_Form
{
    public function init() {
        $this->setMethod('POST');
        //set the viewscript decorator
        $this->setDecorators(array(
            array('ViewScript', array(
                    'viewScript' => '_partial.phtml'
            ))
        ));
    //more follows...
```

Now just render your form as usual

You may have to play with the element decorators to exactly what you want but this should get you close to your goal.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Thanks for help. I have it working now.
I used this lines in view script file to give classes for elements:
<?php $this->element->name->addDecorator('Label', array('tag' => 'dt', 'class' => 'label'));?>
and
<?php $this->element->name->class = @text; ?>
Is it proper way to do it?

Comment: if it works go for it, my understanding of these decorators is a bit tenuous. However I would personally make those decorator changes in the form itself rather then in the viewScript.